# Divide one "column" by another in Tab Delimited file

Tags: python, notepad++, csv

I have many files with three million lines in identical tab delimited format. All I need to do is divide the number in the 14th "column" by the number in the 12th "column", then set the number in the 14th column to the result.

Although this is a very simple function I'm actually really struggling to work out how to achieve this. I've spent a good few hours searching this website but unfortunately the answers I've seen have completely gone over the top of my head as I'm a novice coder!

The tools I have Notepad++ and Ultraedit (which has the ability to use Javascript, although i'm not familiar with this), and Python 3.6 (I have very basic Python knowledge). Other answers have suggested using something called "awk", but when I looked this up it needs Unix - I only have Windows. What's the best tool for getting this done? I'm more than willing to learn something new.

Comment: Editors, such as Notepad++, do not do maths as you want. This is a programming (or scripting) job.

Answer (score 1):

In python there are a few ways to handle csv. For your particular use case
I think `pandas` is what you are looking for.

You can load your file with `df = pandas.read_csv()`, then performing your division and replacement will be as easy as `df[13] /= df[11]`.

Finally you can write your data back in csv format with `df.to_csv()`.

I leave it to you to fill in the missing details of the pandas functions, but I promise it is very easy and you'll probably benefit from learning it  for a long time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I will give pandas a go. It'd be great to use this problem as an opportunity to learn more coding. Will it handle large numbers of rows ok? Or do I need to use any coding techniques to "cache" the rows into memory? (I have 8 GB of RAM)

Comment: You should be fine using pandas

Comment: Thank you for the help, i've successfully got stuck into Pandas now! Unfortunately I've earned negative reputation for this post (not sure why!) but I'll be sure to word future questions differently?